# Retaining Member values of structure across function call

Tags: c, structure

I was wondering if there is any way we can retain the member values of a structure across function calls in case the structure is a local. In case of primitive data types, we declare them as static and data will be retained across function calls. If structure defined in calling portion or as a global variable, I know we can retain this. But just curious if there are any other alternative to retain local structure values across function calls.

```
struct A
{
    int mem1;
}

void f1(void)
{
    struct A var1;
/*Now this var1 is a local variable. Declaring it as static will not help to retain value of mem1 across function calls I guess. */
}
```

Comment: `static` should work regardless of the data type.  If you can't get it to work, post an example of it not working.

Comment: what do you mean across function calls? even a local variable can retain members as long as within scope, unless you are looking for that magical word called pointer

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_(keyword)), and just to set the stage:

> ...static is a reserved word controlling both lifetime (as a static
>   variable) and visibility (depending on linkage). The word static is
>   also used in languages influenced by C, such as Java.

Static is defined as a storage class. A storage class defined the scope and life-time of variables and/or functions. A storage class precedes the type. Regardless of whether it is primitive or not.

Comment: But my main question is with respect to structure members (In case of C++, it could be with respect to class members) and retaining member value across function calls